# AS2 support on BizTalk Server 2010

Tags: actionscript-2, biztalk, edifact

I am running into a scenario, where our client sends the data as EDIFACT file via AS2 protocol and we have hosted our web application in windows server 2003 R2 Standard edition.

Now we want to read the incoming EDIFACT file from our Client via Biztalk server

I googled and found Biztalk 2010 supports AS2 protocol, but we are forced to install biztalk 2006 R2 as we are running Windows server 2003

So could anybody tell me whether Biztalk server 2006 (R2) supports AS2 protocol? If no, then is there any alternative like patches or service pack?

Thanks in advance

Deepan M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, BizTalk Server 2006 R2 supports AS2 out of the box.

There are some Tutorials you can use to understand how BizTalk Server supports AS2.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259975(v=bts.20).aspx

Of course, I must recommend you use a more current version, BizTalk Server 2010 at least.  BizTalk Server 2006 R2 is at or nearing the end of it's support lifecycle.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks, the link you have given is very detailed and I'm good to go ahead


PS: Our application was built on .net 2.0 and not sure about the impact if we migrate it to a newer version. The migration process will be started after detailed analysis of the existing one. Anyways i shall consider your recommendation of using a current version during migration phase of course

Thanks once again for driving me to a good tutorial